# PL/SQL Procedure Output

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm having trouble correctly displaying the results of my procedure. When I execute the procedure that I created. The output should be 'FALSE' since DonorID: 303 has IDStatus = 20 and Paymonths = 0. However, I am getting 'TRUE.' Can someone please help?

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE ddpay_sp (donorid IN NUMBER,
                                      completed_pledge OUT BOOLEAN)
IS
  CURSOR donor_cur IS
    SELECT idstatus,
           paymonths
    FROM   dd_pledge
    WHERE  iddonor = donorid;

p_idstatus  NUMBER(2);
p_paymonths NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
  OPEN donor_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH donor_cur
    INTO  p_idstatus,
          p_paymonths;
    EXIT WHEN donor_cur%NOTFOUND;
    IF p_idstatus = 20 AND p_paymonths = 0 THEN
      completed_pledge := FALSE;
    ELSE
      completed_pledge := TRUE;
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE donor_cur;
END ddpay_sp;

DECLARE
  status BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  ddpay_sp(303, status);
  IF status = TRUE THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: "... DonorID: 303 has IDStatus = 20". Really? How do we know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple rows in your table that match `iddonor = donorid`, Oracle will loop through them until it finds one that doesn't match your `p_idstatus = 20 AND p_paymonths = 0` condition and then exit from the loop with `true`, it will only return 'FALSE' if they all match on the second condition. If you have no rows that match `iddonor = donorid`, then your check will show 'FALSE' [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b9fd10eae40b6a85f34d272de1b0b93)

You need to be clear what should happen when there are multiple rows in `dd_pledge` which have the input iddonor value. E.g. if you wish for it to return `false` if there are any matching rows which have `idstatus=20 and paymonths=0` then you could make the loop `exit` on this condition instead:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE ddpay_sp (donorid IN NUMBER,
                                      completed_pledge OUT BOOLEAN)
IS
  CURSOR donor_cur IS
    SELECT idstatus,
           paymonths
    FROM   dd_pledge
    WHERE  iddonor = donorid;

p_idstatus  NUMBER(2);
p_paymonths NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
  
  OPEN donor_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH donor_cur
    INTO  p_idstatus,
          p_paymonths;
    EXIT WHEN donor_cur%NOTFOUND;
    IF p_idstatus = 20 AND p_paymonths = 0 THEN
      completed_pledge := FALSE;
      EXIT;
    ELSE
      completed_pledge := TRUE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE donor_cur;
END ddpay_sp;
/
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e052b510c655abeabbeafb0ed4c26b3) showing the difference due to `exit` placement